# how to preload cursor in input textbox of modal,bootstrap 3?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

After opening modal, I want cursor to be preload without clicking into textbox. So following is tried.

```
focus-me='focusInput'
```

but it is not working. I am using bootstrap 3. And other links also seen. But it is not working.

Comment: you mean something like this http://jsfiddle.net/r58yf5pg/

Answer (score 0):

Use like this:
`$('#textareaID').focus();`